# Space between components in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

[image: My Custom Picker View]

Does anyone know how I can decrease the spacing between year and month? Also I want minute and seconds more closer, I have been trying to do this for a long time, but could not figure it out. It seems that `widthForComponent` in `UIPickerView` has nothing to do with the spacing between components. Do you guys have any thoughts?

This is how `widthForComponent` looks like in my code.

```
 func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {

            switch component {
            case 0 : return 65
            case 1 : return 50
            case 2 : return 30
            case 3,4 : return 40
            case 5: return 50
            default : return 30
            }
    }
```

Do I have to use `viewForRow` or `attributedTitleForRow` methods to get this? Right now I have not used it.

Comment: @LeoDabus But conventional Date Picker does have year, month, day, time, seconds, AM or PM together. Thats why.

Comment: can you show your date formatter format ?

Comment: @Misha Why do you want to see the dateFormatter part? What it has to do with the spacing between components?

Comment: you are using UIPickerView so it might be because there are spaces in date format

Comment: Why don't you add hour and minute the same column?
If you want to do with separate columns, please write CustomView